# copy from source derived from select query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the `COPY ... FROM ... WITH CSV...` syntax however I'm finding that the filename can be easily derived from the value stored elsewhere in the database and that changing it in a script all the time is a maintenance nightmare.

Is it possible to `SELECT` the filename ie:

`COPY ... FROM (SELECT filename FROM mytable WHERE x=1) WITH CSV...`

Thanks, p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, you can't use a subquery to get the filename.

You can however use dynamic SQL inside a stored procedure. As of version 9.0 you can use DO:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    _file TEXT;
BEGIN
    SELECT filename INTO _file FROM mytable WHERE x=1;

    EXECUTE 'COPY ... FROM ' || _file || ' WITH CSV...;';

    RAISE INFO 'File % imported', _file;
END;
$$;
```